# What is "ld-2.11.1.so" and how can I look at the source code?

Tags: linux

I am trying to catalog uses of the RDTSC instruction on my computer. My first thought was to run my `/lib` folder through `objdump` and search for RDTSC

```
$ for f in ls /lib/*; do echo "*** $f ***" && objdump -d $f | grep -n  rdtsc; done > ~/tmp/out
```

I noticed that a lot of RDTSC is present in the ld.2.11.1.so file. I am pretty sure it has something to do with dynamic library linking, but I'm not sure. My real question is, how can I find the source code so I can see what the RDTSC instructions are for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ld-2.11.1.so` *is* the dynamic linker itself. Most of its sources live in `glibc/elf` directory. You may want to start [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/elf/rtld.c). Look for `HP_TIMING*` macros.

Comment: Thank you. For reference, it is defined in the `HP_TIMING_NOW` macro in (for my architecture) `sysdeps/x86_64/hp-timing.h`.

Answer (score 2):

`ld.so` is part of the C library, which is typically Glibc or EGlibc, depending on the Linux distro.